Should I include a populated manifest file package.xml when creating my package?
I understand that package.xml is used for deploying and retrieving content for "local development" and "hardcoded updates", if I may say. I want to create (a new version of) a managed package that will include new custom fields, layouts and permission sets.
Is the point of the package.xml to remain empty of <types> at the point of a package version creation? Should I be declaring my new fields there?

The package.xml is entirely irrelevant for 1GP and 2GP managed package development.
For 1GPs, you must use the Package Manager to ensure that all relevant metadata is added to the package before uploading a new version.
For 2GPs, anything** in the package directory that is defined for the package in sfdx-project.json is automatically part of the package when you create a new version.
**: Some metadata types cannot be packaged, so be careful.
